# How to retrieve Data from curser

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to retrieve the content of a cursor.

The code for the cursor is as follows:

```
 cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery( "select _id from x where Name = ?", new String[] {str2});
```

Now, it says about everywhere I have to work with getString and getColumnIndex.

But how do I KNOW the name of the column, and so, the argument to give getColumnIndex?

I just want the first (and in this case only) entry in the curser.
Or is the name of the column in this case "_id"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would work in this case is to get the first value of the cursor like this

```
cursor.getInt(0);
```

though a much better approach is to get the `columnIndex` via the `columnName` like this. (In more complex queries this is more or a less a must):

```
cursor.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

And just as a note: Don't forget to call `cursor.moveToFirstPosition()` or `cursor.moveToPosition(position)` before doing something like cursor.getInt(int), cursor.getString(int) etc.

Comment: just trying at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. I only needed a real example